# How would I implement a spring contractor to send blob data to mySql database

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot

Here is my Post class Entity.

The aim is to send images to the database through an API endpoint that I will youse in my website.

```
@Entity(name = "posts")
public class Post {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "Id", nullable = false)
  private String id;

  @Column(name = "Post_title", nullable = false)
  private String title;

  @Column(name = "creator", nullable = false)
  private String creator;

  @Lob
  @Column(name = "post_image", nullable = false)
  private Byte[] postImage;

  @Column(name = "descriptions", nullable = false)
  private String descriptions;

  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }

  public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
  }

  public String getCreator() {
    return creator;
  }

  public void setCreator(String creator) {
    this.creator = creator;
  }

  public Byte[] getPostImage() {
    return postImage;
  }

  public void setPostImage(Byte[] postImage) {
    this.postImage = postImage;
  }

  public String getDescriptions() {
    return descriptions;
  }

  public void setDescriptions(String descriptions) {
    this.descriptions = descriptions;
  }
}
```

This is the java spring controller for the api
The plan is to convert the image with javaScript, I want to have less java code

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/posts")
public class PostController {

    @Autowired
    private PostRepository postRepository;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Post> createPost(@RequestBody Post post) {
        Post newPost = postRepository.save(post);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(newPost, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

here is how I implemented the convention of images into a byte

```
const inputElement = document.getElementById("image-input");

inputElement.addEventListener("change", function() {
  const file = inputElement.files[0];
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
  reader.onload = function() {
    const blob = new Blob([reader.result], { type: file.type });
    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(blob);
    // Now you can send the byteArray to your API endpoint
  };
});
```

Comment: There is no question in your question

Answer (score 0):

Storing images in a database is a bad idea. The wise way is instead of storing the image in a database, storing the image in a file system and then, storing the path/link of that image in the database.  Because images can take space megabytes, this will slow down your server a lot.

If you really want to store the image in a database. You need to store it as blob data.

request the image file separately from the post and make the following change in your post controller and write a method that converts `MultiPartFile` to `byte array`. Finally convert the file to bytes and execute this code before saving the post.  `post.setPostImage(convertFileToByte(image));`

```
  @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Post> createPost(@RequestBody Post post, @RequestPart MultipartFile image) {
          post.setPostImage(convertFileToByte(image));
        Post newPost = postRepository.save(post);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(newPost, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

and do not forget to add this to your application.properties. because the attackers may try to load gigabytes of data into your database.

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
```

As I said before, do not try to save the image directly in your database, it will lead to inflation in your DB.

Comment: Is it good practice to save images as byte text in a database?

Comment: storing images as files on serwer can be also problematic when You have many instances of aplication on different servers, storing in database is OK, but as stated above limit image size, and dont fetch image column from db if it is not needed